# How change Android version when creating AVD?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I started android project in eclipse and I selected in project options android version 4.2.2. Now, when I try create AVD, can't select CPU/ABI, because no system images installed for this target.

Comment: you can edit targetsdkversion in menifest file or you can download the sdkfor your target version

Comment: where menifest file locate ?

Comment: its in your project folder named "AndroidManifest.xml" change  

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

targetsdkversion to your compatible emulator

Comment: Check out this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: I have this there
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"
    />
So, what I should change for change android 4.2.2 to 4.0.4 ?

Comment: it is correct for this version you need to download the SDK for 4.2 just go to Android SDK Manager and install API for Version 4.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So open the `SDK Manager` and download the desired `CPU image` and `SDK version` you would like to have:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

U can change it in android manifest where we have option to change versions in terms of api levels like this...

android:minSdkVersion="10"

android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
Eg. If u want to keep ur basic version 2.3.3 then above code is for u

Answer (score 0):

its in your project folder named **"AndroidManifest.xml"** change

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
```

change targetsdkversion to your compatible emulator which you have created

**OR** 
if you want to run it in 4.2

Download the latest API for **version 4.2** from **Android SDK Manager**

Answer (score 0):

Right Click On your Project

1. Select Properties
2. Select Android from Left Side
3. Select the project build target for which u have the system image and press OK

[image]

Comment: I have there only 4.2.2 version. When trying add else version - the list is empty.

Comment: @JohnOggy Refer to Emil Adz Answer so that u can install the system image for 4.2.2 or some other version